# New users not working on MySQL 5.6 in Amazon RDS

Tags: amazon-rds, mysql-5.6

I'm using the CREATE USER and GRANT commands as mentioned here http://dev.n0ise.net/2012/09/amazon-rds-mysql-add-additional-users-with-limited-previledges/

When I try to connect I get this in MySQL Quer Browser:

```
Could not connect to host '...sa-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com'.
MySQL Error Nr. 0
```

Output in MySQL Workbench:

```
Your connection attempt failed for user 'site' from your host to server at ...sa-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306:
  MySQL server has gone away
```

**Some details:**

- MySQL version: 5.6.13
- Credentials are typed correctly. When I miss them I get the standard 1045 access denied error.
- The user created with the instance and another limited user I created some weeks ago are working fine
- Same commands worked fine on a non RDS server

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you run `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;` after granting?

Comment: Yes. I also tried to restart the instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I forgot that I had created a stored procedure to set the time zone after every connection made.

Looking at the server log I found that the problem was that the new users didn't have permission to execute it.

Comment: Thank you, this is a wonderful tip for something to be aware of.